# Create a quad of squares inside a larger square

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hopefully, this image will explain what I'm trying to do... in CSS...

[image]

Ive managed to complete almost all of this. Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/8xNu7/)**, displaying what I've got so far... unfortunately, I cannot seem to place the squares side by side (tried float), and instead, they're appearing in a vertical column.

Any suggestions?

**HTML...**

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>    
</div>
```

**css...**

```
.content-container {
    max-width: 570px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 50px solid #e81354;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

.inner-square {
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Try float again.  It really is the correct answer.

Comment: Tried it on both the `content-container` and the `inner-square`... doesn't work. Try it.

Comment: You need to set you position correctly.  And you need to make sure you have exactly enough space, or the div will not float.  Just the percentages alone could throw that off.

Comment: Oh.  You also need the float on only the ones on the left.  You can't use the same class for all 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you set the `width` to `50%` but not minus the `10px` margin, also your HTML code has line breaks between the `div`s, so you should set the `font-size` to 0 for the container (to eliminate the `4px` of the line break):

```
.content-container { 
  ...
  font-size:0;
}
.inner-square {
  background: #cccccc;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  height: calc(50% - 8px);
  margin: 5px;    
  display:inline-block;
}
.inner-square:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left:0;
}
.inner-square:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8xNu7/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You need to add `float:left` to `.inner-square`.
2. Your squares aren't taking the form you want because you have a `margin: 5px` on `.inner-square`. So, your `.inner-square` widths are currently 50% + 50% + (4*5px). Because these are bigger than the width of your box, the second square takes the next available space: the space underneath. So, try `margin: 5px 0` and your problem goes away.

Comment: Yep. That was it... It worked. Such a small oversight changes everything. Thanks.

Comment: `50% + 50% + (4*5px)` - this is not true because there is still `4px` of the line break between the 2 divs (in a line).

Answer (score 0):

i found this code lined them up best i would put the style into the css in final copy tho `<div class="content-container"style="position:absolute;">
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"style="float:right;margin-top:-478px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>
    <div class="inner-square"style="float:right;margin-top:-239px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x230"></div>

</div>`